# tightlist error using Pandoc with Markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am using pandoc v. 1.18 on Mac OS 10.12 to transform this markdown file to a pdf, using a simple command line:

```
# A list that does not work
- one
- two
- three
```

And I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.53 \tightlist

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\tightlist` was introduced with pandoc 1.14 (see [this commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/commit/d248c9d6382ded310564424bf110cdf159785fac)). The most probable cause for this error is that you are using a [template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) from a previous version and did not update it. This can be fixed by adding a couple of lines to your latex template. They can be found at `$DATA-DIR/templates/default.latex` for regular latex and `$DATA-DIR/templates/default.beamer` for beamer. You'll need to add those two lines (before the `\begin{document}`):

```
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
```

To make sure this does not happen again with future evolution of the templates, it might be a good idea to fork the [pandoc-templates repository](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates).