# Pandoc: generate compilable .tex from markdown

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I have started using Markdown to write my Latex PDFs, and so far I am impressed by the amount of boilerplate it takes away.

However, I find Markdown not as expressive as Tex, and therefore in some situations would like to write the document in Markdown, convert to tex, then add some Latex-only stuff and only then convert to PDF.

However, converting .md to .tex with Pandoc does not yield an compilable file: it only contains the body of the file, not the "document setup".

Example, the following .md file:

````
```haskell
data Expr = I Int
```
````

Converts to:

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{data} \DataTypeTok{Expr} \FunctionTok{=} \DataTypeTok{I} \DataTypeTok{Int}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}
```

Obviously this is missing some stuff like the document class, start of document and the imported packages. Is there any way to generate this complete file instead of just the body? Or if not, can anyone at least tell me what package the Shaded, Highlighting, KeywordTok, DataTypeTok and FunctionTok commands are pulled from? Then I can add these imports myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandoc creates small snippets by default. Invoke it with the `--standalone` (or `-s`) command line flag to get a full document.